# How to create valid xml using xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to view the below defined xml schema into my expected xml. Can anyone help me what to write in XSD. Thanks in advance. 
XML SCHEMA:

```
<xs:element name="Animal">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT in XML:  `<Animal type="carnivore">Tiger</Animal>`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the schema? Do you want to _associate_ your instance with your schema, so it can be validated? There is no such thing as "expected output", unless you are using the schema to generate instances. In that case, you probably want to write something in Java. Is that it?

Comment: yes i want to associate my instance with schema. 

I want to display the above excepted output using XSD file.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a schema containing only the element you showed, you can generate the instance you want in Java using JAXB. I added some context to your example, and included a namespace. This is the full XML Schema file (I called it `animals.xsd`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://animals"
           targetNamespace="http://animals"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Animal">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>   
</xs:schema>
```

Using the `xjc` tool (XSD to Java Compiler) you can generate classes from XML Schemas. So you can simply run:

```
xjc animals.xsd
```

And it will generate these files

```
animals/Animal.java
animals/ObjectFactory.java
animals/package-info.java
```

Place these in your classpath. Now you can write a simple program where you can create instances using that class, and then serialize it to XML using a JAXB marshaller:

```
import animals.Animal;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Animal tiger = new Animal();
        tiger.setType("carnivore");
        tiger.setValue("Tiger");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animal.class);
        Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(tiger, System.out);
    }
}
```

The result will be printed to the console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Animal xmlns="http://animals" type="carnivore">Tiger</Animal>
```

Comment: If you simply want to associate the instance to the schema, then you need to add one or more attributes, depending if you have namespaces or not. If the schema (above, with a namespace) and instance are in the same directory, you can use `<Animal xmlns="http://animals"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://animals animal.xsd" 
 type="carnivore">Tiger</Animal>`.